# Accessing state or props from functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i'm trying to accessing variable/state in functional component from other component. i found out i can save the in some global state like **redux** or local storage. but i don't want to use any of them. i also found out about `lifting state up` but can't understand about it.

below is an example for my case. let's say i want to generate a lucky number from functional component **GenerateLuckyNumber**. and i call the component from **showLuckyNumber**. but i need to save all the list of lucky number that have been generated. i create a hook state to store all lucky number. but i dont know how to retrieve them from **GenereateLuckyNumber**

any idea how to to it?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const GenerateLuckyNumber = () => {
  const [luckNo, setluckNo] = useState(1)
  
  const changeCatName = () => {
    setluckNo(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
  }
  
  return (
  <>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeCatName()}>
    <Text>Hello, Your Lucky Number is {luckNo}!</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </>
  );
}

const showLuckyNumber = () => {
  const [listLuckyNumber, setlistLuckyNumber] = useState()
  //how to save all generated number from functional component to state in this component
  
  return (
  <>
    <GenerateLuckyNumber/>
    <GenerateLuckyNumber/>
    <GenerateLuckyNumber/>
  </>
  );
}

export default showLuckyNumber;
```

Comment: *lifting state up* your state is already lifted up. What you miss is a callback, passed from the parent component to the child component, the callback would be defined in parent but called from the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component can provide an optional callback function as a prop, which it would invoke whenever it "generates a lucky number".  For example:

```
export const GenerateLuckyNumber = ({onGenerate}) => {
```

And within the component:

```
const changeCatName = () => {
  const luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  setluckNo(luckyNumber);
  onGenerate && onGenerate(luckyNumber); // invoke the callback
}
```

Then any component which renders a `<GenerateLuckyNumber/>` can optionally supply it with a callback:

```
const showLuckyNumber = () => {
  const [listLuckyNumber, setlistLuckyNumber] = useState()
  
  const handleNewLuckyNumber = (num) => {
    // do whatever you like with the newly generated number here
  };
  
  return (
  <>
    <GenerateLuckyNumber onGenerate={handleNewLuckyNumber}/>
    <GenerateLuckyNumber onGenerate={handleNewLuckyNumber}/>
    <GenerateLuckyNumber onGenerate={handleNewLuckyNumber}/>
  </>
  );
}
```